# Vs Code и Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Раньше писал на pycharm, однако на данный момент не достаточно мощностей пк. Было принято решение найти альтернативу - выбрал Vs Code, однако столкнулся с рядом мучительных проблем

1. Как импортировать классы или функции? В pycharm я мог навестись на название класса, нажать alt + enter и он сам выполнит импорт. Вопрос в том как это работает в Vs Code , мб надо какие то плагины скачать? (Я знаю, что там есть автоимпорт для питона, но когда ты условно копируешь код, удалять название класса и писать его заного лишь чтобы отработал импорт выглядит убер костыльно и ущербно)
2. Переопредление методов - в pycharm это команда cmd+n на маке ( generate code), где можно было выбрать overriding methods и выпадал целый список методов, которые можно переопределить. Это очень удобно в использовании, однако в vs code кроме сниппетов, где ты пишешь название функции и она сама пишет сигнатуру, я ничего не нашел. Грустно(

Помогите пожалуйста, не хотелось бы терять такие полезные фичи, к которым я очень сильно привык

Comment: Pylance пробовали https://habr.com/ru/company/microsoft/blog/558388/ ?

Comment: Да, он у меня скачан, однако как заявлено в самом расширении, он не работает. К примеру я пишу datetime, а он даже не предлагает мне такого варианта импорта(а это стандартный пакет на секундочку). Выглядит очень странно